# Reversing order of a tuple of list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

I have a tuple ([1,2,3], [4,5,6]) and I want to reverse the list inside so that it becomes ([3,2,1],[6,5,4]) without having to create a new tuple and adding elements to it. The closest I've gotten is:

```
my_func(....):
   for i in tuple(...):
     i = i[::-1]
   return tuple(....)
```

problem is that while i prints out what I want..the tuple was never changed

Answer (score 8):

Tuples are immutable but the objects contained by them can be either mutable or immutable, so if we modify a mutable object contained by the tuple then the change will be reflected at all the references of that object, that includes the tuple as well.

As in this case we've lists, so, all we need to do is to loop over the tuple and call `.reverse()` on the lists.

```
>>> t = ([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
>>> for x in t:
...     x.reverse()
...     
>>> t
([3, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4])
```

Another example:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> t = (x, 'abc')
>>> x.reverse()
>>> t
([3, 2, 1], 'abc')
>>> x
[3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

As frostnational says, tuples are immutable, so you will have to create new ones.

You could do something like this:

```
>>> a = ([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
>>> b = map(lambda t: reversed(t), a)
>>> for sublist in b:
...     for item in sublist:
...         print(item)
... 
3
2
1
6
5
4
```

Comment: No. The tuple contains only references to the lists. The references will be the same, but the lists itself are mutable. This way it is possible to reverse the content of the lists. The tuple is still immutable. Think about the constant tuple content as about the constant sequence of the list identifiers. The truth is that such a list cannot be used as a key of dictionary. This is because such tuple is not hashable.

Comment: Good point, in this context the lists can probably be modified. It's still useful to keep data immutable sometimes, as other people may be relying on the fact that these lists do not change. Plus, we're not creating new lists here, only small iterators, so the memory cost is very little.